# how can to show corresponding Childs on hover of any (parent)node in organization highchart?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to show child(highlight child and parent both) on hover of any parent node in an organization chart, but it is not working that way, can anyone please help on how can I do that?

Here is code that I am referring:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-yzjnxb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour seems to not occur in the 10.2.1 version. I'd recommend always using the latest Highcharts version.

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-ab46yw?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts